# How to use nodejs & socket.io server for multi user in a non-blocking way?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, exec, threadpool, socket.io-1.0

I'm working with NodeJs from a couple of time & it was doing a really good job when there is only IO. And then I faced this challenge.

We have a game in which every time on an average 250 users play. Currently its back-end server is running on java. But now we want to convert it in NodeJs.

So we were going good until when we reached to the game engine. Where there is so many CPU-bound jobs. When a user is getting served these CPU-Bound requests, all others are getting blocked. This is really normal I know so we tested all the solutions of this problem before abandoning the project.

Used the following:

1. callback
2. thread and threadPool from node_module [webWorker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads)
3. created separate js file for all CPU-Bound jobs and ran them in [process.exec](http://www.graemeboy.com/node-child-processes)
4. [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)
5. created each thing in different module

But except process.exec & cluster all are in vain. In these two solution cluster is also too much unpredictable. Because it happened that in a worker multiple requests are assigned & in the front there is a CPU-Bound job, in that case again same issue.
Only process.exec is working good. But we have so many CPU-Bound tasks, if we do a separate file for each of them then it will be a mess.

So I want to know if it is not at all possible in NodeJs or not. Anyone of stack-overflow community faced this issue and solved it or anyone want to give any solution regarding this, a big thanks to all of them...